# Minimal polynomial of $\sqrt2+\sqrt5$

Tags: polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Obtain a polynomial of lowest degree with integral coefficient, whose one of the zeroes is $\sqrt5+\sqrt2$.

Comment: OK, what have you tried?

Comment: ive tried getting the terms and squaring both sides of the polynomial to get a fourth degree term x^4 - 14x^2 + 9 = 0

Comment: but the answer in the solution is  a*x^4 - a*14x^2 + 9 = 0, where a is a constant integer

Comment: but i dont get how u can multiply an integer in all the coefficients and the roots dont change

Comment: You're missing an $a$ in front of the constant $9$... that's just giving all solutions by trivial leading term multiplication.

Comment: oh, i didnt notice that. thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Because the specified root is composed of two incommensurable square roots, the minimal polynomial will be quartic and the other roots are formed by changing the signs of $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt5$.
$$(x-\sqrt2-\sqrt5)(x-\sqrt2+\sqrt5)=x^2-2\sqrt2x-3$$
$$(x+\sqrt2-\sqrt5)(x+\sqrt2+\sqrt5)=x^2+2\sqrt2x-3$$
$$(x^2-3-2\sqrt2x)(x^2-3+2\sqrt2x)=x^4-14x^2+9$$

Comment: ok thanks a lot, do check out my previous comments and see if u can find an explanation for the constant "a" part tho :)